# Ticks command is not working for one axis

Tags: plotting, complex, ticks

```
roots = NSolve[Sin[2z] == Cos[Sin[z]] + 1 && -2π <= Re[z] <= 2π && -2π <= Im[z] <= 2π, z]; 
w = z\.roots;    
ListPlot[{Re[w], Im[w]}, Ticks -> {{-2π, -π, 0, π, 2π}, {-2π, -π, 0, π, 2π}}]
```

In this code, `Ticks` command is not working properly, that is, real axis range is not showing between $-2\pi$ to $2\pi$, where as imaginary axis is showing properly.

Also, is there any command for complex list plot and complex plot? I mean a command such that the following command works

```
ComplexListPlot[w, Ticks -> {{-2π, -π, 0, π, 2π}, {-2π, -π, 0, π, 2π}}]
```

instead of

```
ListPlot[{Re[w], Im[w]}, Ticks -> {{-2π, -π, 0, π, 2π}, {-2π, -π, 0, π, 2π}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
 roots = Values@
       NSolve[Sin[2 z] == Cos[Sin[z]] + 1 && -2 π <= Re[z] <= 
          2 π && -2 π <= Im[z] <= 2 π, z];

    pts = Join @@ ReIm[roots];

    ListPlot[pts, PlotRange -> {{-2 π, 2 π}, Automatic},
Ticks -> {{-2 π, -π, 0, π, 2 π}, {-2 π, -π,  0, π, 2 π}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
ListPlot[ReIm[w], 
 Ticks -> {{-2 π, -π, 0, π, 2 π}, {-2 π, -π, 0, π, 2 π}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

[image]

You can also use `Transpose[{Re[w], Im[w]}]` in place of `ReIm[w]`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the structure of `{Re[w], Im[w]}`:

```
{{-5.44099, -5.44099, -5.38849, -5.38849, -5.18796, -5.18796, <<517>>}, 
 {-2.83853, 2.83853, 0.561567, -0.561567, -3.38889, 3.38889, <<517>>}}
```

These are two long lists: all the real parts, followed by all the imaginary parts. This is not a list of pairs, as desirable to obtain your plot. You should `Transpose` that list to obtain what you want:

```
Transpose@{Re[w], Im[w]}

(* Out 
{{-5.44099, -2.83853}, {-5.44099, 2.83853}, {-5.38849, 0.561567}, {-5.38849, -0.561567}, <<519>>}
*)
```

So this would work:

```
ListPlot[Transpose@{Re[w], Im[w]}, Ticks -> {{-2 π, -π, 0, π, 2 π}, {-2 π, -π, 0, π, 2 π}]
```

A better alternative, however, is to use the built-in `ReIm`, which is listable, so it will automatically thread over your list of complex and give you the format you need:

```
ReIm[w] == Transpose@{Re[w], Im[w]}
(* Out: True *)
```